# Not able to get and persist data in to data base using swagger api doc with spring boot and tables having onetomany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

Below is controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{empId}" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmpById(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId){
    Employee emp=null;
        try{
            emp=empService.getEmpById(empId);
            log.debug("employee_controller - getting employee of id...."+empId);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("employee_controller - error occured while getting employee" +e);
        }
    return new <>(emp,HttpStatus.OK);    }
```

Below is Service code:

```
 public Employee getEmpById(Integer empId) {

        Employee emp = null;
        try {

            log.debug("Employee_Service - getting employee by id..." + empId);
            emp = empDao.findOne(empId);
            System.out.println("emp data is========" + emp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Employee_Service - errror occured during getting employee of id" + empId);
        }
        return emp;
    }
```

*emphasized text*    :Getting null while getting and even not able to persist data if tables 
     having ontomany relation.If i remove relation woring fine.

[InputType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhhC.png)

*stacktrace*
**Hibernate: 
    select
        employee0_.empid as empid1_1_1_,
        employee0_.empname as empname2_1_1_,
        dept1_.empid as empid3_0_3_,
        dept1_.deptid as deptid1_0_3_,
        dept1_.deptid as deptid1_0_0_,
        dept1_.deptname as deptname2_0_0_,
        dept1_.empid as empid3_0_0_ 
    from
        emp_tbl employee0_ 
    left outer join
        dept dept1_ 
            on employee0_.empid=dept1_.empid 
    where
        employee0_.empid=?
2018-09-13 15:22:58 - binding parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhhC.png) as [INTEGER] - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhhC.png)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        emp_tbl
        (empid, empname) 
    values
        (null, ?)
2018-09-13 15:22:58 - binding parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhhC.png) as [VARCHAR] - [john]
Hibernate: 
    select
        dept0_.deptid as deptid1_0_1_,
        dept0_.deptname as deptname2_0_1_,
        dept0_.empid as empid3_0_1_,
        employee1_.empid as empid1_1_0_,
        employee1_.empname as empname2_1_0_ 
    from
        dept dept0_ 
    left outer join
        emp_tbl employee1_ 
            on dept0_.empid=employee1_.empid 
    where
        dept0_.deptid=?
2018-09-13 15:22:58 - binding parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhhC.png) as [INTEGER] - [2]
2018-09-13 15:22:58 - Employee_Service - errror occured during saving employeecom.hcl.ontToManyWithH2.Entities.Employee@799f9b7c

2018-09-13 15:22:58 - employee_controller - saving employeecom.hcl.ontToManyWithH2.Entities.Employee@799f9b7c
**

Comment: Could you add the exception to your question?

Comment: @Casper:getting null value i debugged

Comment: So no exception?

Comment: Null pointer exp

Comment: It could help if you copy the whole stack trace and paste it in your question.

Comment: @Casper i have pasted